# Convert Byte String to Int in Scheme

Tags: algorithm, scheme, byte

I have code like this to convert hex into byte string

```
(define (word->bin s)
  (let ((n (string->number s)))
    (bytes (bitwise-and (arithmetic-shift n -24) #xFF)
    (bitwise-and (arithmetic-shift n -16) #xFF)
    (bitwise-and (arithmetic-shift n -8) #xFF)
    (bitwise-and n #xFF))))
(word->bin "#x10000002")
```

I'm thinking of a similar function to convert binary into integers, then print it. The end result is the binary translated to hex. Some helpful links:
http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/372/html/mzscheme/mzscheme-Z-H-11.html#node_sec_11.2.1

[http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/bytestrings.html#(def.*((quote.*~23~25kernel)._bytes-~3estring/utf-8))](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/bytestrings.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._bytes-~3estring/utf-8)))

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for, or even if you're using [PLT](http://plt-scheme.org), but if you do, then you should look at the `integer-bytes->integer` and `integer->integer-bytes` functions that [are included](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/numbers.html) in PLT.  Note that these create byte strings with *binary* content -- so it might be different than what you're trying to do here.

(And if you're using version 372, then you should really upgrade.)

Comment: Well, if this is part of a homework, then your teacher might require you to write a solution.