# building an signed integer from 4 bytes?

Tags: java, binary

I have been learning a bit about binary and memory and I looked how int is being written, and from what I understood it basically writes 4 bytes, where the max number for a signed is where your 4 bytes are `127`:

```
    byte a = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
    byte b = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
    byte c = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
    byte d = Byte.MAX_VALUE;

    System.out.println((a << 24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + (d << 0));
```

And then I shift left by a byte (8 bits) every time).

But the maximum number i get is `2139062143` instead of `2147483647`, why is that?

Comment: Why are you using `+`?

Comment: You are printing 0x7f7f7f7f.

Comment: INT_MAX  is 2147483647 and -2147483648 because 0 takes one spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In binary, `MAX_VALUE`s for each type start with a `0` bit and continue with all `1` bits. That means, to get `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you'll need a `0` bit followed by 31 `1` bits:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE:    01111111111111111111111111111111
```

However, you're not producing that. You're using `Byte.MAX_VALUE` repeated four times. This means you have a `0` bit followed by seven `1` bits followed by a `0` bit followed by seven `1` bits and so on:

```
Byte.MAX_VALUE:       01111111
Byte.MAX_VALUE×4:     01111111011111110111111101111111 (2,139,062,143)
```

Since `-1`s are composed solely of `1` bits, you can get what you want with one `Byte.MAX_VALUE` followed by three `-1`s:

```
Byte.MAX_VALUE:       01111111
-1:                   11111111
Byte.MAX_VALUE, -1×3: 01111111111111111111111111111111
```

---

A second problem will arise when you try to combine these. When Java converts a negative `byte` to an `int`, it becomes a negative `int`, which means a whole lot of `1`s are added to the left side of it in binary. Thus, you'll need to use `& 0xff` (or [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-)) to strip those added bits from each `byte`.

It's also better to use `|` instead of `+`, because it fits the meaning of what's going on more precisely.

So, to produce `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```java
byte a = Byte.MAX_VALUE;
byte b = -1;
byte c = -1;
byte d = -1;

System.out.println(((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) | ((c & 0xff) << 8) | ((d & 0xff) << 0));
```

Comment: Got it. -1 & 0xff gives me 255, i need 127,255,255,255 in order to create 01111111111111111111111111111111 which the first bit represents if the signed number is negative or positive where if it was 1 it would be negative. Am i right?

Comment: But what if I want to do it negative?

Comment: Yes. Which negative value?

Comment: If i want negative max value of singed integer, I have to follow the 2's complement which is negative_value = ~value+1 according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422442/1609248, how'd i do it in this case?

Comment: `MIN_VALUE`s are one `1` followed by all `0`s. So, you'd use `Byte.MIN_VALUE` followed by three `0` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the MSB must be zero, all other bits need to be 1. This gives you `0x7FFFFFFF`, the maximum value for a signed 32-bit integer in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Answer (score 0):

`byte` is signed between -128 and 127. So -1 are 8 ones.

As shifting `<<` is done after promoting `byte` to `int`, you would get an int -1 of 32 ones.

So do

```
int a = 0xFF; // Or 0b1111_1111
int b = 0xFF;
int c = 0xFF;
int d = 0xFF;
```

Or do:

```
byte[] bytes = { (byte)-1, (byte)-1, (byte)-1, (byte)-1 };
int n = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```

All ones one can get as:

```
int n = -1;
int n = ~0; // Ones complement
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840190/java-convert-4-bytes-to-int but I did exactly like in this answer, except the OR and AND operators, theres something I am misunderstanding? Shouldnt 4 bytes with value 127 give you signed integer max value which is 2147483647

Comment: 127 is binary 0111_111, Byte.MAX_VALUE. So no. You can shift a byte (sign extended to an int by the shift op) as: `(b & 0xFF) << ...`.